# Ruby way to Generate HMAC-SHA256 signature for Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I have been working with Amazon's Producct Advertising API for a while now. I was successful in integrating all features provided by this in my app. But the only one remaining is the Cart Create operation which requires an HMAC-SHA256 signature to be generated and used for all the cart actions to be performed. I have gone through the docs and all the threads available regarding this issue but nothing seems to me work in my case.

I have even gone through multiple gems but no one provides a solution for this. I am currently using `Vacuum` gem with Ruby 2.2.3, Rails 4.2.5.

**Question:** I mainly  need to understand **how to generate this HMAC signature** so that I could use it in all cart related actions.

Answer (score 2):

The HMAC signature can be created using Ruby's OpenSSL support. This must then be Base64 encoded so that it can be sent over the wire. The basic premise is as follows

```
require 'openssl'
require 'Base64'

key = "your-secret-access-key"
data = "data you want signed"

signature = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, data)).strip()
```

Adapting the above to your needs, the `key` is your AWS Access Key, and `data` is the string representation of the request you want to send, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/HMACSignatures.html).

How you construct the `data` string is implementation specific but a common approach is to build a canonical string from the actual request object (most commonly `Net::HTTP:HTTPRequest`). Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use `Base64.strict_encode64(str)` instead of `Base64.encode64(str).strip`

Comment: Thanks!! This was what I was looking for.